# Find the max subsequence of the given sequence of numbers (in a list)

Tags: c, list

```
void *max_subsequence(node *head){

    node *max=head;
    int count=0;
    int count1=0;
    int i;

    while(head!=NULL){
        count=0;
        while(head->num < head->next->num){
            count++;
            head=head->next;
        } 
        if(count > count1){
            count1=count;
        } 

        head=head->next;
        max=head;
    }  
}
```

This code doesn't compile and I don't know why.
It should find the largest increasing subsequence of the given sequence stored in a list. Can anyone give me a hint?

```
typedef struct node1{
    int num;
    struct node1 *next;
    }node;
```

Comment: In `while(node->num < node->next->num)` you don't know that `node->next != NULL`. This would be a runtime error.

Comment: `max_subsequence` must return a value.

Comment: I know it must return a value, I know what I would do after this, in a code. I was thinking about "remembering", in a max variable, node which is the beginning of the max subsequence.

Comment: While defining struct you used node1, but while creating head you are using node

Comment: Can you include the compiler error and include that in your title?

Answer (score 1):

Change your while loops from `node->` to `head->` in both. Also be sure to heed Weather Vane's comment about a potential runtime error.

Comment: Yes, `node` is a type, not a variable.

Comment: I did, I wrote it like that in original code, on my computer. It was an error while translating. Sorry!

Comment: @Ross now you know why we ask for the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem.